# Approve SharePoint Online document while viewing in Word Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-web-apps, approval

When using desktop versions of Microsoft Office (i.e. Word and Excel) alongside SharePoint 2010 workflows in SharePoint Online, we have the option to open approval tasks while viewing the document or the approval email - there is an "Open this task" button at the top saying "Open this task".

Is there anything similar to this in Office Web Apps (i.e. Word/Excel Online) while using Microsoft Flows?

We have been showing our customer some Microsoft Flow based approvals for SharePoint Online documents, but they are concerned most of their management will not like switching back and forth between Word/Excel, SharePoint Online and approval emails, etc, just to approve a document.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is not such functionality in Flow for you can directly approve/reject in flow or in the email with the approval action in Flow. The user do not need to switch back and forth. Go to flow or open the notification email. And you can check the history of approval in Flow>Approvals. 
[image]

If the user want to record the process via SharePoint Task list, you can create/update task list item in the same approval flow according to the Flow approval process.